# Long message ends up empty at destination

Tags: gammu

Why is the following (decoded) message cut correctly at the 160th character, as expected:

```
00000000010000000002000000000300000000040000000005000000000600000000070000000008000000000900000000100000000011000000001200000000130000000014000000001500000000160000000017000000001800000000190000000020
```

The destination receives:

```
0000000001000000000200000000030000000004000000000500000000060000000007000000000800000000090000000010000000001100000000120000000013000000001400000000150000000016
```

While the following message is just ending up empty at the destination:

```
[aaaaaa] bbbbbbbb | cccc_ccc
 \_ dd (eeeeeeee)
 \_ fff ff - f.fff ffffff ffffffff ffff ff ffffffff.ffff.ff ffff 389
 \_ 2020-07-07 20:10:27 +0200
 \_ ggggg ggggg ggggggggg GGG gg gggggggg g ggggg gg gggggggg ggg gggg gggg ggg ggggggg:

 hhhhh Y44wCg6vu8m6CeG5ZB8MA2nif9l0nG7/Nceec5NA7UjZO+OKHOAjCy5hdeAdt+WVD2U=|n
```

I'm simply inserting it into outbox. I know I should use outbox_multipart for longer messages, but that is not the question. I am wondering why the second message is ending up empty at the destination while the first is just cut off.

(Gammu 1.39 on SLES15)